# Primefaces Calendar popup not working

Tags: java, calendar, primefaces

I have upgraded primefaces to version 3.3. I realize now that calendar datepicker doesnt popup any more. i tried to downgrade it but it doent work. here is the code.

```
<p:calendar value="#{transaction.startDate}" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
```

in java i use java.util.date and set a value on startDate.
It shows the value i put for startDate but it doesnt popup the date picker when i click on the input field. Anybody knows what the problem is?
Here is the javaScript stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDate' of null jquery.js:56
$.extend._setDateFromField jquery.js:56
$.extend._showDatepicker jquery.js:56
b.event.dispatch jquery.js:16
b.event.add.bD.handle.bB jquery.js:16
b.event.trigger jquery.js:16
b.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:16
bF.extend.each jquery.js:16
bF.fn.bF.each jquery.js:16
b.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:16
b.each.b.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.js:16
a.fn.extend.focus jquery.js:33
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.focusFirstInput primefaces.js:12
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend._show primefaces.js:12
PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.show primefaces.js:12
b.oncomplete primefaces.js:12
i.complete primefaces.js:1
b.Callbacks.e jquery.js:16
b.Callbacks.bD.fireWith jquery.js:16
bF jquery.js:23
b.ajaxTransport.send.bv jquery.js:23
```

Comment: Do you have errors in javascript console (firebug, chrome developer tools)?

Comment: Yes i have it here:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDate' of null jquery.js:56
$.extend._setDateFromField jquery.js:56
$.extend._showDatepicker jquery.js:56
$.extend._attachments jquery.js:56
b.event.dispatch jquery.js:16
b.event.add.bD.handle.bB jquery.js:16

Comment: did it worked with previous version? what version was it ? try to clean your cache... all other primefaces components work for you ?

Comment: Is your start date null?

Comment: any chance you tried to add another jquery library ?

Comment: I used 3.2-SNAPSHOT and I didnt have the problem. when i upgraded to 3.3 and theme southstreet 1.0.5 then i had the problem. i downgraded to 3.2 but it doesnt help. how to clean the cache?

Comment: Hi Nikita startDate returns new Date(). it is not null.

Comment: How to change the jquery library in primefaces. I didnt need to deal with that before.

Comment: Can you print full javascript stacktrace to you question?

Comment: try ctrl + f5 to reload the page...

Comment: Daniel i tried that too. still the same. I tried with IE also but the same thing happens there too.

Comment: say , any chance you changed your import in the `transaction` bean ? the import of the scope, session or request , etc... are they from `javax.faces.bean` package ?

Comment: There is no change in the transaction bean.I use Spring webflow. All beans are in scope session.

Comment: I found something intresting. if startDate is null. the the popup shows onload and then it works. but i want to to have default values.

Comment: @user1057347 try to remove `effect` and `pattern` attributes.

Comment: Hi I think this is not Primefaces fault. I use JDK 1.7 in this pc. Calendare works fine on production which uses 1.6. Is there any change on java.util.date in 1.7?

Comment: Seems I can reproduce it with a custom pattern like this: pattern="MMM yyyy". Try removing the pattern.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in Java. I used java 1.7 When i downgraded the java to 1.6. It worked.

Comment: Now, that's an explanation. My guess is that you changed other things without realizing. I can't see why it even *could* be related. If it is, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try mode="popup" instead of effect="fadeIn"